# Poor FPS performance with antialias:true in Threejs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, three.js

Whenever I enable antialias on the WebGL renderer, the FPS goes from 60 to about 25.

```
this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
});
```

This seemed to start occurring after I added multiple scenes and had to manually clear the depth. Of note I also hit 60 FPS on mobile safari just fine but not desktop or chrome.

What might cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one of the things may be the resolution of your scene on desktop.

Also check the device pixel ratio.

Comment: Yea I found that it was tanking when I would use it on my retina laptop and then wouldn't on my desktop monitor.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by [mjanisz1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43585439/7914498) is probably correct, in that it has to do with your resolution and dpr combination, since most browsers use MSAA, which is basically upscaled render and expensive. I would suggest you take a look at FXAA here https://github.com/mattdesl/three-shader-fxaa. It offers a quality-performance trade-off that is usually worth it.

Comment: Yea thats great I was looking for something like this. I thought it can't be that hard to blur the edges. New to the whole GL world so still finding these morsels :).